# Scroll horizontally in Rhomobile (Rhodes)

Tags: rhodes, rhomobile

I am using Rhomobile to develop apps. I have wide images on an app and would like to enable horizontal scrolling to view the images. Vertical scrolling is automatically available but not for horizontal scrolling. Here's what I found:

- I cannot scroll horizontally in Rhodes simulator.
- I cannot scroll horizontally in Android emulator.
- I cannot scroll horizontally in HTC android.
- But I can scroll horizontally in Samsung Galaxy Tab.

I've tried to put "overflow:scroll", setting div width, body width, but the result are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be a limitation on the device or emulators browser, as Rhodes is using a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I removed jqtouch.css and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Scroll : 'horizontal'
```